# Is $X^8+1$ reducible in $\mathbb R[x]$?

Tags: polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

How to check irreducibilty of $X^{2n}+1$  in $\mathbb R[x]$?

$n\geq 2$

I dont know how to do this .Any help

Answer (score 6):

Hint:
$$x^4+1=(x^2+\sqrt2 x +1)(x^2-\sqrt2 x +1).$$
In general, any polynomial of degree $\ge 3$ is reducible in $\Bbb R[x]$: if some root is real, is obvious; if all the roots $\alpha$ are complex, $(x-\alpha)(x-\bar\alpha)$ is a real factor (why?).

Comment: If $x-\alpha $ is a root why will $x-\alpha^- $ be  a root

Comment: @learningmaths, $P(\alpha)=0 \implies 0=\overline{P(\alpha)}=P(\overline\alpha)$ because...

Comment: "$P$ is a polynomial" is it right?

Comment: @learningmaths, right.

Comment: If $x-\alpha $ is  a root and $x-\alpha^{-}$ is a root how to show $(x-\alpha )(x-\alpha^{-})$ is a root

Comment: @learningmaths, the goal is to prove that $(x-\alpha)(x-\bar\alpha)$ is real. Write $\alpha = a+bi$ and do the calculations.

Comment: Yes that is true.But you have said the product is a real factor How to show that the product is a factor

Comment: @learningmaths, are you asking if the product of factors is a factor?

Comment: Yes how to show that

Comment: @learningmaths, what is the *definition* of factor?

Comment: If $\alpha $ is a factor then $P(\alpha )=0$

Comment: @learningmaths, a factor a a polynomial such that...

Comment: $p(a)=0,p(a^{-})=0 $is it true $p(|a|^2)=0$

Comment: @learningmaths, $\alpha$ *isn't* a factor, is a root. the *polynomial* $(x-\alpha)$ is a factor.

Comment: @learningmaths, $g(x)$ is a factor of $p(x)$ when $p(x)=g(x)h(x)$.

Answer (score 2):

Every real polynomial factors into linear and quadratic polynomials.

Comment: Nitpick: non-constant (or as I sometimes prefer: monic, since $1$ factors as an empty product).

Answer (score 2):

If *n* has at least one odd factor, then $n=a(2k+1)$, and we can write $x^{2n}+1=\Big(x^{2a}\Big)^{2k+1}+1$, which is divisible by $x^{2a}+1$. If, however, *n* has no odd factors, then it is of the form $2^p$, in which case $x^{2n}+1=\Big(x^{2^{~P}}\Big)^2+1=\Big(x^{2^{~P}}+1\Big)^2-2~x^{2^{~P}}$, which for positive values of *p* is a difference of two squares, and thus decomposable over the reals.